# Testing a module

Tags: jhipster

I just implemented a Jhipster module to provide [Maven site generation as well as maven release process within Jhipster](https://github.com/Tcharl/generator-jhipster-enterprise-pom).

I implemented mocha tests to verify that files are generated (which pass), but it looks like they aren't generated in a real scaffolded context (if you have any clue on the error, I would be really thankful).

The only way I found to test that module with a scaffolded sample  is to publish it in the npm registry in order to be able to select it in module choices radio, but it's not really a good option, as it exposes a non working module on the Jhipster marketplace (I'm really sorry about it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test a module locally, do the following:

- run `npm link` in your module directory
- generate a project
- run `npm link generator-jhipster-enterprise-pom` in your project

Now when you run `yo jhipster-enterprise-pom` it will use your local code instead of requiring installation from npmjs.

Looking at your module's code, it looks like you renamed the `app` folder to `server`.  A yeoman generator runs the code found in the `app` folder which is why your local test is failing.  According to the [Writing Your Own Yeoman Generator docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html):

> The default generator used when you call yo name is the app generator. This must be contained within the app/ directory.

It's currently accessible by running `yo jhipster-enterprise-pom:server` but I imagine you don't want the `:server` included in the default command.